# Bash Scripts for inserting .txt files to csv

Tags: shell-script, csv

I'm looking for a script that would allow me to be able to compile a bunch of `.txt` files into a `.csv` for reference.

I would need to have the `.txt` file name as the first A fields, and the content of the `.txt` file in the B fields. Anyone have any suggestions?

This was the script that I used before,  -d, "./*.txt >> test.csv

I am fairly new to scripting, and will be using Lynda to study further, but any help will be great. Thanks all.

Comment: For such questions always give example input and output.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried? How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: Do input files have only one line of content? Can the content have double quotes? Please show some sample input and desired output.

Comment: Forgive me, i'm still really new to Linux and scripting as a whole. This was the linux command I tried before. -d, "./*.txt >> test.csv

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the input. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I echoed the current date out to files named with the current time's nanosecond value. Then I ran the for loop you see below. The other commenter above is accurate in asking about single lines. Newlines and other control chars may hose how the CSV displays. If you need, you can use `tr` to remove control chars.

Notice the interior double quotes were escaped.

```
# for file in *.txt ; do echo -e "\"$file\",\"$(cat $file)\"" ; done > DudesFile.csv
# cat DudesFile.csv
"522846064.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:07 EDT 2018"
"528189011.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:08 EDT 2018"
"534462603.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:09 EDT 2018"
"539602831.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:10 EDT 2018"
"544644085.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:11 EDT 2018"
"549794326.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:12 EDT 2018"
"554869915.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:13 EDT 2018"
"559829685.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:14 EDT 2018"
"564845609.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:15 EDT 2018"
"570065970.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:16 EDT 2018"
"575184986.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:17 EDT 2018"
"580279560.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:18 EDT 2018"
"585486035.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:19 EDT 2018"
"590751832.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:20 EDT 2018"
"596243540.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:21 EDT 2018"
"601355464.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:22 EDT 2018"
"606470579.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:23 EDT 2018"
"611651121.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:24 EDT 2018"
"616854098.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:25 EDT 2018"
"622111044.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:26 EDT 2018"
"627396500.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:27 EDT 2018"
"632593596.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:28 EDT 2018"
"637756851.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:29 EDT 2018"
"643109987.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:30 EDT 2018"
"648373987.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:31 EDT 2018"
"653597441.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:32 EDT 2018"
"658773675.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:33 EDT 2018"
"663844298.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:34 EDT 2018"
"668910760.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:35 EDT 2018"
"674208819.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:36 EDT 2018"
"679508914.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:37 EDT 2018"
"684725670.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:38 EDT 2018"
"689989415.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:39 EDT 2018"
"695392140.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:40 EDT 2018"
"700430922.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:41 EDT 2018"
"705658665.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:42 EDT 2018"
"711117890.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:43 EDT 2018"
"716275104.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:44 EDT 2018"
"721507284.txt","Mon Apr 30 16:38:45 EDT 2018"
```